# getting error while using pixellib model.segmentFrame() to segment an image taken from camera

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, image-segmentation, pixellib

```
import pixellib
from pixellib.instance import instance_segmentation
import cv2

segmentation_model = instance_segmentation()
segmentation_model.load_model('mask_rcnn_coco.h5')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # # Apply instance segmentation
    res = segmentation_model.segmentFrame(frame, show_bboxes=True)
    image = res[1]

    cv2.imshow("instance segmentation: ", image)

    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

while running the above code i get the following error displayed:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[4], line 6
      3 ret, frame = cap.read()
      5 # # Apply instance segmentation
----> 6 res = segmentation_model.segmentFrame(frame, show_bboxes=True)
      7 image = res[1]
      9 cv2.imshow("instance segmentation: ", image)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pixellib\instance\__init__.py:442, in instance_segmentation.segmentFrame(self, frame, show_bboxes, segment_target_classes, extract_segmented_objects, text_thickness, text_size, box_thickness, save_extracted_objects, mask_points_values, output_image_name, verbose)
    440 if verbose is not None:
    441     print("Processing image...")
--> 442 results = self.model.detect([new_frame])    
    445 r = results[0] 
    447 """Filter unused detections and detect specific classes """

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pixellib\instance\mask_rcnn.py:2469, in MaskRCNN.detect(self, images, verbose)    2466 results = []    2467 for i, image in enumerate(images):    2468     final_rois, final_class_ids, final_scores, final_masks =\
-> 2469         self.unmold_detections(detections[i], mrcnn_mask[i],    2470                                image.shape, molded_images[i].shape,    2471                                windows[i])    2472     results.append({    2473         "rois": final_rois,    2474         "class_ids": final_class_ids,    2475      "scores": final_scores,    2476         "masks": final_masks,    2477  })    2478 return results

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pixellib\instance\mask_rcnn.py:2416, in MaskRCNN.unmold_detections(self, detections, mrcnn_mask, original_image_shape, image_shape, window)    2413 full_masks = []    2414 for i in range(N):    2415     # Convert neural network mask to full size mask
-> 2416     full_mask = utils.unmold_mask(masks[i], boxes[i], original_image_shape)    2417     full_masks.append(full_mask)    2418 full_masks = np.stack(full_masks, axis=-1)\    2419     if full_masks else np.empty(original_image_shape[:2] + (0,))

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pixellib\instance\utils.py:566, in unmold_mask(mask, bbox, image_shape)
    564 y1, x1, y2, x2 = bbox
    565 mask = resize(mask, (y2 - y1, x2 - x1))
--> 566 mask = np.where(mask >= threshold, 1, 0).astype(np.bool)
    568 # Put the mask in the right location.
    569 full_mask = np.zeros(image_shape[:2], dtype=np.bool)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:338, in __getattr__(attr)
    333     warnings.warn(
    334         f"In the future `np.{attr}` will be defined as the "
    335         "corresponding NumPy scalar.", FutureWarning, stacklevel=2)
    337 if attr in __former_attrs__:
--> 338     raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
    340 if attr == 'testing':
    341     import numpy.testing as testing

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'. `np.bool` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here. The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
```

i'm using the latest version of tensorflow with python version 10.
i think the error is due to the pixellib library using an older version of numpy and in the newer version some things are deprecated, which is causing the issue.

I have tried downloading a previous version of numpy in an attempt to resolve this error but it didn't work.

is there a way to resolve this error?
If live image is not working is there a way we can just segment a single image imported from somewhere else?
If the issue is with pixellib then is there any other library that i can leverage to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: needs more error checking. `if not ret: ...` -- please don't "quote" the tracebacks. they are not prose. that makes them unreadable.. post them and then wrap them in \`\`\` at the beginning and end. they are code and need to be presented as such.